# ts-rest fastify server gets killed on ResponseValidationError

Tags: fastify

I am new to ts-rest and fastify. I setup a server as mentioned in the docs. this works fine. But I have the problem, that when I set `responseValidation: true` and have get a `ResponseValidationError` the socket hangs up and the server is killed, instead of getting a `500` response as described in the docs.

How can I fix this?
I know thy the validation fails, but how can I catch `ResponseValidationError` and send a response with status code `500`?

```
throw new ResponseValidationError(appRoute, responseValidation.error);
      ^
Error: [ts-rest] Response validation failed for POST /contacts/contact: [
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "object",
    "path": [
      "_id"
    ],
    "message": "Expected string, received object"
  },
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "object",
    "path": [
      "organisation_id"
    ],
    "message": "Expected string, received object"
  }
]
```

Comment: It's a bug in the library, see this https://github.com/ts-rest/ts-rest/issues/510. I fixed it using `patch-package` as I am not sure when the dev will get around to it.